# Cannot set `:p` as abbreviation of `:pu`

Tags: abbreviations

I am trying to set up an abbreviation for `:pu` as `:p`, so it is more consistent with `:y` and `:d`.

```
cnoreabbrev p pu
```

However this doesn;t work. It will just return `cnoreabbrev p pu` on the command message without doing anything. Why is that?

### Edit

Taking this text as an example, where `[]` is the cursor

```
hel[]lo
world
foo
```

I run `:2y` to copy line 2, and I want to paste it after line 3 with `:3p`, instead of `:3pu`.

Didn't realize `:p` represent `:print`, is it possible for me to overwrite that, making `:p` to represent `:pu`?

Comment: What are the steps you are taking? Eg, run the command, then type `:p `? Or something else? By default p is short for print, which prints the current line without a range.

Comment: Didn't realize `:p` represents `:print`. How can I overwrite that? I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: The abbreviation actually works as expected... But it only recognizes `p` as a word by itself. So `:3 p` will trigger it (as `:3 pu`) while `:3p` will not. Also note that the abbreviation triggers elsewhere in the command line (and search prompt, etc.) so it has many adverse side effects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can't rename built-in commands (the ones started with lowercase letters).

So no, you can't make `:p` represent `:pu`.

But you can use `:copy` (that has builtin synonym `:t`) and/or `:move` commands.

In you case it is simple:

```
:t3
```

Comment: This is very useful. Looking at `:help :copy` right now, it seems that this command is not binded to any key by default?

Comment: @JohnWinston It's not much different from `Y`/`:yank` followed by `3jp` or `:+3put`; it's just ex versus normal and is linewise. `:copy` does have advantages! e.g., no cursor movement, arbitrary ranges, etc. Just different styles of doing things.

Comment: Or is this key possible to be binded? Unlike other command, this key requires a range and an address.